# Input validation + jquery ui tooltips result in double tooltips

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, jquery-ui-tooltip

On an internal website I am using input text fields with "required" and "pattern" specified. This results in a tooltip message apparently from the browser (Chrome), saying: Please fill out this field.

By specifying my own text with "title" I can overwrite this, but I need to format the tooltip text with bold, newlines etc. For this reason I have switched to jquery ui.
Now a problem arises, because now I end up with two tooltips. The jquery ui with my text and a native tooltip from Chrome saying "Please fill out this field".

Among others I tried:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message { display: none; }

document.getElementById("xx").setCustomValidity('')
```

It seems the first one is not supported anymore. And the second one I cannot get to change anything - besides it seems to just change the text, not fully remove it.

I need the validation, so I cannot remove "required" and I can also not disable validation by using novalidate or similar.

Is there really no way to get rid of this native validation tooltip?

Comment: Can we see the html you're using for these tooltips?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go for a workaround instead.
Rather than adding my jquery ui tooltip on the textbox itself, I have added a span with an information mark () after it. Then added the tooltip to this span instead.